# Solve : $x+y=2010$, $(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})(\sqrt[3]{x}+11)(\sqrt[3]{y}+11)=2942$

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, symmetric-functions

> Given$$x+y=2010,\\(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})(\sqrt[3]{x}+11)(\sqrt[3]{y}+11)=2942,$$
>   find the value of $\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}$.

**My attempts:**

Let $u=\sqrt[3]{x} , v=\sqrt[3]{y}$.

$(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)=2010 \tag{1}$

$(u+v)(uv+11u+11v+121)=2942
\tag{2}$

$(1)+(2)$:

$$(u+v)(u^2+v^2+11u+11v+121)=4952$$

How to proceed?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch variables to $t=\sqrt[3]x$ and $u=\sqrt[3]y$ before you dive too deep into the algebra.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ known to be integers?

Comment: Problem statement don't mention on this matter. I think $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ${(u+v)}=\frac {2010} { (u^2-uv+v^2)}$ and ${(u+v)}=\frac {4592} {(u^2+v^2+11u+11v+121)}$ so $\frac {2010} { (u^2-uv+v^2)}=\frac {4592} {(u^2+v^2+11u+11v+121)}$ looks like an obvious strategy, did you try that already? Seems unlikely to help, but worth looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've done, we have that
$$(1)\iff 2010=(u+v)^3-3uv(u+v)\tag3$$
and that
$$(2)\iff uv(u+v)=2942-11(u+v)^2-121(u+v)\tag4$$

From $(3)(4)$, we have
$$2010=(u+v)^3-3(2942-11(u+v)^2-121(u+v)),$$
i.e.
$$t^3+33t^2+363t-10836=0\tag5$$
where $t=u+v$.

Now checking if a divisor of $10836=2^2\times 3^2\times 7\times 43$ is a solution, we see that $t=12$ is a solution to have
$$(5)\iff (t-12)(t^2+45t+903)=0$$
where $t^2+45t+903\gt 0$ since $45^2-4\cdot 1\cdot 903\lt 60^2-4\times 900=0$.

It follows from this that $$\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}=\color{red}{12}$$

Comment: Yep, same approach as my solution, just factorised a bit more clearly. Nice.

Comment: Thank you very much, mathlove, stanley dodds.

Answer (score 2):

u and v look quite similar, so I will just use a and b instead:
$$3(a+b)(ab+11a+11b+121)+(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=3\times2942+2010=10836$$
$$(a+b)(a^2+2ab+b^2+33a+33b+363)=10836$$
$$(a+b)((a+b)^2+33(a+b)+363)=10836$$
$$(a+b)^3+33(a+b)^2+363(a+b)-10836=0$$
Solving for $a+b$, the real root to this is $a+b=12$, so the answer is 12. I'm not sure if this is the desired approach, but it works.